# Google Maps Javascript - Make Marker Bounce

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps

I have been playing around with Google Maps javascript and was hoping someone could help me make my markers bounce. I have an array of markers, and am hoping that onmousehover of a link, div or heading(h1) I can make a particular marker bounce.

```
function initMap() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 11,
        center: {
            lat: -37.800426,
            lng: 145.038494
        }
    });
    setMarkers(map);
}

// Data for the markers consisting of a name, a LatLng and a zIndex for the
// order in which these markers should display on top of each other.

var stores = [
    ['A', -37.771624, 144.888128, 1],
    ['B', 37.843956, -144.994875, 2],
    ['C', -37.818086, 144.995699, 3],
    ['D', 37.812697, -145.229200, 4],
];

function setMarkers(map) {
    // Adds markers to the map.
    for (var i = 0; i < stores.length; ++i) {
        var store = stores[i];
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: {
                lat: store[1],
                lng: store[2]
            },
            map: map,
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
            title: store[0],
            zIndex: store[3],
        });
        attachStoreTitle(marker);
    }
}

// Attaches an info window to a marker with the provided message. When the
// marker is clicked, the info window will open with the secret message.
function attachStoreTitle(marker, storeName) {
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: marker.title
    });

    marker.addListener('click',
        function() {
            infowindow.open(marker.get('map'), marker);
        });
}
```

The other main problem I'm having with the listener's is calling the right marker, considering all the data is in an array.

Answer (score 2):

Marker animations are documented here: [Google Maps Marker Animations](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-animations?hl=de)

You could add following method:

```
function toggleBounce() {
  if (marker.getAnimation() !== null) {
    marker.setAnimation(null);
  } else {
    marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
  }
}
```

and now add a click listener to every marker in your for loop:

`marker.addListener('click', toggleBounce);`

If you want to invoke the bounce on hover, add a `mouseover` listener instead.

Other events can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events?hl=de)

Comment: I have added the toggleBounce function to to bottom of the script. However I'm a little confused as the markers are in an array. How do I get each marker to bounce individually?

Comment: If you look in the top script, you will see the array of data for the different markers. How can I get each marker to bounce either when I click them or onmouseover.

Comment: @Matthew just do the same as you do with the `attachStoreTitle(marker)`. 
Run the `marker.addListener('mouseover', toggleBounce);` afterwards.

Comment: So now my code is as follows,
'var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
position: {lat: store[1], lng: store[2]},
map: map,
animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
title: store[0],
zIndex: store[3],
});
attachStoreTitle(marker);
toggleBounce(marker);
                  }'
I have also added 'marker.addListener('mouseover', toggleBounce);'

Comment: 'function toggleBounce(marker) {
  if (marker.getAnimation() !== null) {
    marker.setAnimation(null);
  } else {
    marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
  }
marker.addListener('mouseover', toggleBounce);
}'

Comment: can you provide a jsfiddle script please? i cant help you with this information